# Required field missing account current object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom, object, visual

I created a custom object, with a button to my visual page.

When I click on my button, I get the good redirection.
The problem is that I am trying to insert in my custom object (child of account) some info.

```
akta__c aktaplus = new akta__c(name='test', Type_of_alert__c='yeyey');
insert aktaplus;
```

Because my akta__c is a child of account, I have to set up the required field account (which is normal)
But because I click on the button from a specific account that already exist, I would like that field to be automatically fixed to the account from which I click on the button so the information is stored in my account page, inside my custom object

How can I do that ?

Comment: how you are opening visualforce page from account record page layout?

Comment: from a button created. the button is a list button that redirect to the visual page. The button appear in my custom object. So I don't know how to populate the account field so it's linked to the account from where I clicked @patelkiran3090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, if applicable, using a [Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview.htm&type=5), optionally with [Predefined Field Values](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5) (although they aren't required simply to populate the master-detail field) to create this child record.

Using a Quick Action will allow you to maintain compatibility if you should move to Lightning.

If you have other reasons to utilize a Visualforce page, change the button's content source to URL, and add the referring Account Id as a URL parameter to the page. Then, in the page's controller, use [`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm#!) to obtain the value.

Comment: Hello there , thank you for the answer, I tried with the URL, it's working in classic, but when I go to lightning the URL look like : source=aloha#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJhZGR so I cannot pass the account id as parameter.