# How to select a full account

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, visual

I would like to create a variable called acc and to select a full account that is inside my accounts:

Something like :

```
Account acc = [select account from account where name='p2'];
```

That would save the full account where the name is equal to p2 inside the variable acc

Comment: What do you mean by full account ? What exactly are you trying to do and what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I am trying to do that https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271154/required-field-missing-account-current-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in SQL you can do select * to select all fields. But in SOQL, you cannot do that. You should specify all fields.